# jQuery mobile swipe does not work on Windows Phone

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone, swipe, mousemove

I use the swiperight and swipeleft events from jQuery Mobile. They work pretty fine on my desktop pc and on an iphone while developing but when I test it on my windows phone both events just don't fire.

As simple as it seems to be:

```
<div class="swiper">Content</div>
```

and the Script

```
$(".swiper").swiperight(function(event){
    alert('swiperight');
});
$(".swiper").swipeleft(function(event){
    alert('swipeleft');
});
```

Same problem with $(".swiper").live('swipeleft swiperight')

Does anyone have a solution for this? According to http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/08/01/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-2-0-alpha/ they have A-grade support for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the Internet Explorer browser on Windows Phone doesn't support touch events. This means that jQuery Mobile events for swipe do not work on Windows Phone. As far as I know, there is no solution or workaround, because the browser doesn't fire the necessary events for detecting swiping motions.

Comment: it's correct that they do not fire touch events, but they do fire mouseup and mousedown events in the same way, the desktop browser does. The problem seems to be: as soon as I move inbetween the mousedown and mouseup, it doesn't fire at all (not even the mousedown)

Answer (score 1):

As windows phone 7 devices does not support mouse move events, swipe right/left event won't work. This issue is resolved in windows Phone 8 devices.

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030700/1482739](http://Reference%20link)