# windows phone: jquery mobile swipe not recognized

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, swipe

I'm making an HTML + jquery mobile app. It works fine on my pc but when I try it out on my windows phone the swipe event doesn't seem to get fired..

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function () {
 goToNextPage()
});
```

Comment: Do you use any mobile framework like PhoneGap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7/IE9 does not support mousemove event so there is not way for jquery mobile to recognize swipe event.

Some mobile frameworks like [Apache Cordova (PhoneGap)](http://phonegap.com/) provide workaround for this by adding special shim between native (silverlight) touch events and web browser control to fix missing mouse events. [Demo](http://www.risingj.com/archives/209)

**Update**

This works fine on Windows Phone 8 since it supports mousemove.

Comment: okey thank you! at the moment I'm not planning on using phoneGap but I might end up just having to! thank you for taking the time to answer

Comment: do you happen to know if Windows phone 8 supports mousemove event (and if this would result in jquery mobile working on windows phone 8)

Comment: Yes. mousemove is fully supported on WP8 and the swipe gesture works fine. Just tested on WP8 device and 'Swipe to navigate' jqm 1.3 demo page http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html

Answer (score 1):

Tested the jquery mobile swipe example on a Lumia 920, and it worked perfectly. So trust it works well for WP8 devices. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html. I actually used a slide menu plugin with swipe function and it worked on the Lumia 920. Here is the link to the plugin : https://github.com/tegansnyder/JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu